# How to show the basic formula of the Mean Residual Life Function in survival analysis?

Tags: calculus, statistics

The basic quantity employed to describe time-to-event phenomena is the survival function, the probability of an individual surviving beyond time x (experiencing the event after time x). If $T$ is time of death, survival at time $x$ is is defined as
$S(x) = Pr (T > x)$.

Also, the survival function is the integral of the probability density function, $f(x)$, that is,

$$ S(x)=Pr[T>x]=\int^\infty_x f(t)\,dt$$

The mean residual life function is defined as
$$\operatorname{mrl}(x):=E[T-x|T>x]$$

Can anyone tell me how to get the formula below?
$$
\operatorname{mrl}(x) =\frac{\int^\infty_x (t-x)f(t)\,dt}{S(x)}=\frac{\int^\infty_x S(t)\,dt}{S(x)}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $S$ is the survival function of a nonnegative random variable denoting time of death of a life, or time to event of somethig that has finite mean or expected life time. Then, by Chebyshev-Markov's inequality
$$t S(t)=t P[T>t]\leq E[T\mathbb{1}(T>t)]\xrightarrow{t\rightarrow\infty}0$$

One approach to you problem is integration by parts:
$$S'(t)=-f(t)$$
$$\int^\infty_x(t-x)f(t)\,dt=\int^\infty_x(t-x)d(-S(t))=-S(t)(t-x)|^\infty_x+\int^\infty_xS(t)\,dt=\int^\infty_xS(t)\,dt$$

---

In general, if $T$ is a nonnegative random variable with  $E[T]<\infty$ one may use Fubini's theorem to estimate $E[T-x|T>x]$, $x\geq0$, as follows
$$E[T-x|T>x]=\frac{E[(T-x)\mathbb{1}(T>x)]}{P[T>x]}$$
The numerator is
\begin{align}
E[(T-x)\mathbb{1}(T>x)]&=\int_\Omega (T(\omega)-x)\mathbb{1}_{\{T>x\}}(\omega)\,P(d\omega)\\
&=\int_\Omega\Big(\int^\infty_0\mathbb{1}_{(x,T(\omega)]}(t)\,dt\Big)\,P(d\omega)\\
&=\int^\infty_0\Big(\int_\Omega\mathbb{1}_{(x,\infty)}(t)\mathbb{1}_{\{T>t\}}(\omega)\,P(d\omega)\Big)\,dt\\
&=\int^\infty_0\mathbb{1}_{(x,\infty)}(t)\Big(\int_\Omega\mathbb{1}_{\{T>t\}}(\omega)\,P(d\omega)\Big)\,dt\\
&=\int^\infty_x P[T>t]\,dt=\int^\infty_x S(t)\,dt
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. One follow-up question is from the definition mrl(x) = E(X - x | X > x), how to get to the formula?

Comment: @Mariana: I don't know if you have some knowledge of Lebebsgue integration. If so, you can appeal to Fubini's theorem to estimates the quantity you described. I made an edit to my posing showing one way to do it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get $$E[T-x|T>x]=\frac{E[(T-x)\mathbb{1}(T>x)]}{P[T>x]}$$

Comment: In general, if $A$ is an event with $P[A]>0$, and $X$ is a random variable, $E[X|A]=\frac{E[X\mathbb{1}_A]}{P[A]}$. Again, this may require a little integration theory. For simple functions $X=\mathbb{1}_B$, you get the familiar conditional probability $P[B|A]$. by linearty of expectation, if $X=a_1\mathbb{1}_{B_1}+\ldots+a_k\mathbb{1}_{B_k}$, you get $P[X|A]=a_1P[B_1|A]+\ldots+a_kP[B_k|A]$. then, by approximating nonnegative functions by monotone sequences of simple functions you get the result for $X\geq0$. An then the extension to any (integrable function) holds by $X=X_+-X_-$.